# Joining to a domain from a DC

Tags: domain-controller, login

I currently received an error from a computer stating that the trust relationship to the domain is not trusted and cannot be verified etc... I was able to log into the system and remove the computer and add it to a "workgroup" I logged back in as the only local account user I know in order to join the computer back to the domain.

Unfortunately when I got to add the computer to the domian, UAC pops up and prevents me from adding to the domain. When I got to disable UAC on the account, same thing; UAC prevents me from accessing the controls. I have no ability to select YES and move forward, clearly this is not the admin account for the local computer. I then used MMC to open user groups and was unsuccessful in joining the account to the administrator group as well as enabling the admin account for log in. In essence I'm logged in as a local guest account and have no access in adding the computer to the domain. I was wondering if there was a way to add the computer back to the domain through the DC so please advise.

Keep in mind, I am working remotely and do not have direct access to this workstation. Otherwise I would have already been able to find my way into the computer under an admin account.

Answer (score 7):

No. You must be a local admin on the machine to join it to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

@MDMarra

You were correct that I needed to be a local admin on the system to rejoin the computer to the domain. In order to do this of course, I had to re-enable the local admin account for log in privileges. I booted into safe mode with networking and logged in as the local guest account. From there I was able to then enable the local admin account without UAC getting in the way. After this I changed the admin password and then rebooted the machine to log in as the local admin. From there I was able to add the computer to the domain and restore the trust relationship.

Thanks for the advice.